# Can a user FTP when SFTP is setup with vsFTPd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, sftp

Help I have setup vsFTPd to use SFTP with this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04 and it works perfect even with the changes I have made. But I have a specific application that can only use FTP but as my Config forces TLS it wont accept the connection

Any ideas that will let me run both?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
```

Along with

```
ssl_enable=YES
```

This allowed me to have explicit FTPS and old plain FTP to run on the same time on port 21.